# How can I have a property that can be an array of strings or a function that returns an array of strings?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like:

```
interface ListColumn {
  filters: Array<string | string[]> | (arg0: any) => string[],
  ...
```

And then I have code which does:

```
class Helpers {
  static isFunction (arg: any) {
    return arg && typeof arg === 'function';
  }
}
```

...

```
if (Helpers.isFunction(obj.filters)) { obj.filters = obj.filters(config.screenWidth); }
```

and I get: Not all constituents of type '(string | string[])[] | ((arg0: any) => string[])' are callable. Type '(string | string[])[]' has no call signatures.

I seem to only be able to get around this by declaring filters as `any` or performing casting such as:

```
if (Helpers.isFunction(obj.filters)) { obj.filters = (column.filters as (arg0: any) => string[]) (config.screenWidth);
```

Is there a better way to get around this?

Comment: Can you show `isFunction`? I don't think it's a proper type guard.

Comment: @youdateme, sorry I realized I left that out and just edited the question to add it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isFunction` isn't an actual type guard. TypeScript does not know that if it returns true that means its argument is a function. You have to use `is` here:

```
class Helpers {
  static isFunction (arg: any): arg is (...args: unknown[]) => unknown {
    return arg && typeof arg === 'function';
  }
}
```

[docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

Comment: just curious, https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/ban-types/#default-options says `Avoid the Function type` so this fails my linting..  Is there another way to do this generically without using `Function` -- meaning, this helper function could be used with `() => void` or `() => something` or `(a,b,c) => something` etc..  How can I account for all that?  Or am I just supposed to disable eslint for this line?

Comment: `(...args: unknown[]) => unknown` is my go-to type for any function. I don't know why I put `Function` there lol. (corrected)

Comment: Thanks!  One more question-- can you explain how to read `...args: unknown[]` ?  that is saying that the actual `arguments` object in javascript is like an array of unknown things-- basically zero or more arguments?  That syntax is really strange to me!

Comment: It's saying the function takes any amount of args that are unknown which is basically every function.